# Upgrading from Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, upgrade, laravel-5

I made a website and I spend about 2 month on it, I made it by Laravel 4.2 and now I see the new version of Laravel released (Version 5).

My Questions:

1. Should I change and work with Laravel 5?
2. What happens if I don't change to Laravel 5? Does Laravel 4.2 Works or it has security issue?
3. Why does [Taylor](https://github.com/taylorotwell) change the coding style of Laravel? *(I know Laravel 4 had lot of diffrent with Laravel 3, And this is not good for Developers.)*

**Edit:**

4. I learned Laravel in about 2 weeks, How much time do I need to learn or migrate to Laravel 5?

Comment: I would say don't rush into it, and complete your current project with Laravel 4.

Comment: No reason to rush. Laravel 5 breaks compatibility with all existing packages. I just spent 3 hours trying to fix my dependencies, eventually gave up and decided to wait for vendors to do that. The new messy structure and the switch to plural namespacing are not helping either.

Comment: For future readers, there's now an [automated upgrade tool for Laravel projects](https://laravelshift.com) named *Laravel Shift*. Definitely worth it for the 4.2 upgrade.

Comment: Just used the service mentioned by **Jason McCreary** to [automatically upgrade Laravel 4.2 to 5.0](https://laravelshift.com/upgrade-laravel-4.2-to-laravel-5.0). Worked great! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer question 2 - Laravel 4 will continue to work. Taylor provides back-ports for security issues - so it will continue to remain a viable framework.

In saying that - t[he upgrade guide from 4.2 to 5.0 shows you how to upgrade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0). Most websites can be upgraded in less than 4 hours (from reading various forum posts) - so you could just upgrade and take advantage of the many awesome new features.

Comment: Thanks, if your can Please answer to other questions too.

Comment: No - the other questions are opinion based. Only you can answer those. There are no 'right' or 'wrong' answers to those.

Comment: Thanks, What about my new question, Item number 4

Comment: I kinda already answered that - most people tend to upgrade in less than 4 hours. Just follow the upgrade guide step by step...

Comment: 4 Hours! Good luck with that if you have a large site and use Sentry. I gave up after 2 days of messiness.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first and third question, you have to deside for yourself.
That being said, in order to make a fact-based judgement, I would advise you this:

1. Check out the [free Laracasts serie introducing you to Laravel 5](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals)
2. Listen to the [Laravel podcast](http://www.laravelpodcast.com/) episodes 18-21 where Taylor Explains new features and why he changes things like the file structure
3. Read the release notes (as The Shift Exchange noted) to find out new and useful functionality in Laravel 5

Answer (score -3):

No need, the difference between Laravel 4 and 5 is mainly structurally, both depend on third party libraries via composer.

Comment: It is not mainly structural. Namespaces, middlewares, environments. Those are not structural.

Comment: middlewares replace filters, Namespaces existed before also, the first thing I would do with a fresh L4 installation is removing models, controllers folders and create an App folder. Environments also existed in L4 but they work differently in L5.